# Max concurrent connections for MySQL

Tags: mysql

Is there a difference in the number of maximum concurrent connections between mysql standard edition and mysql enterprise edition? supposing the two mysql is on a two different server with the same specifications: 4Core Intel CPU and 4GB Memory

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about server configuration parameters, not programming

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference of number of maximum concurrent connections, it depends of `max_connections` parameter on my.cnf, and may you will need to change other config parameters as well.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_connections